# I need help making and displaying a List

Tags: c#, list, random, code-generation

I wish to program a Skateboard Trick Generator for me and some friends and I can't seem to get the List to show on the Label and randomly pick a trick.

```
 private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //new random
        static Random rnd = new Random();
        
        string[] words = { "Kick Flip", "Heel Flip", "Tre Flip" };

        lblTrick.Show(words[rnd.Next(0, words.Length)];
```

If anyone could help I would love that.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to show? A single trick from the list at random? All of the tricks?

Also, please paste your code into your question as text. It makes it a lot easier to get help.

Comment: I want a trick to picked out of the list and have it be displayed on the label by a button click. I will soon add the stances as well.

Comment: So, do you know how to pick a random item from a list?  Have you researched this at all?  There are thousands of posts here on the topics related to your project; help yourself (literally) to all the knowledge you need.

Comment: I have tried to research it but it's hard finding a C# way of doing it. I either find Java, Python, or when I do find C# it's not in the correct scenario. I will do more research tho, thank you.

Comment: Should I add a whole new page for tricks and stance for the List?

Comment: just put c# in your search args ;) If you are just starting out in c# and come from other language backgrounds, you might find that your browser has _learned_ your past searching behaviours, try your search in a different browser or a private session, to see if you get better results.

Comment: I was recently programming in Java and Python and I find C# to be easier for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are confusing a few different language implementations.

For help on anything .Net, you should consult the MS Docs first, try this for [Random.Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-6.0).

In .Net we assign the content of a `Label` using the `.Text` property:

```
private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //new random
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    
    string[] words = { "Kick Flip", "Heel Flip", "Tre Flip" };

    lblTrick.Text = words[rnd.Next(words.Length)];
}
```

Comment: Accept this as an answer with the tick to the left of the post, some of us frown upon thankyou comments ;) I'll take it though

Comment: I need 15rep for it but I will for sure:)

Answer (score -1):

This is the new code that works with Stances, Rotations, and Tricks. I also added buttons to hide the rotations because some tricks are way too hard with it.

```
    {
        //new random
        Random rnd = new Random();

        //tricks, stances, rotations
        string[] rotation = { "BS 180", "FS 180", "BS 360", "FS 360" };
        string[] stance = { "Goofy", "Regular", "Nollie", "Fakie" };
        string[] tricks = { "Kick Flip", "Heel Flip", "Tre Flip", "Varial Flip", "Varial Heel", "Lazer Flip", "Ollie", "BS-Shuv", "FS-Shuv", "3-Shuv", "FS 3-Shuv", "Hard Flip", "Inward Heel", "Double Flip", "Double Heel", "" };

        //random display of tricks and stance
        lblTrick.Text = (tricks[rnd.Next(0, tricks.Length - 1)]);

        lblStance.Text = (stance[rnd.Next(0, stance.Length - 1)]);

        lblRotation.Text = (rotation[rnd.Next(0, rotation.Length - 1)]);'
```

Thank you for help, now I will finish this and get my friends to give it a go:)

Comment: Given `stance` has 4 elements, what does `rnd.Next(0, stance.Length - 1)`?

Comment: Thought I needed it to randomize. Im getting back into programming after a decade.

Comment: `rnd.Next(0, stance.Length - 1)` generates 3 random numbers (0, 1, 2). The second parameter is an exclusive upper-bound. Since `stance` has 4 values you should do `rnd.Next(0, stance.Length)` to get a chance of getting any of the 4.